# Get aria-expanded value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I didn't find a way to get aria-expanded value from DOM.

```
<a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" href="#collapse-One" data-parent="#accordion-1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>
    test
</a>
```

I want to test if it's `true` then I can change `<i>` class to `fa-search-minus`. I tried this but I always get an undefined value:

```
console.log($(this).find('a.aria-expanded').val());
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`aria-expanded` is an attribute on the element, not a class, so the selector is incorrect. Secondly, you should use the `attr()` function to get the value of that attribute. `val()` is intended to retrieve the `value` attribute from form related elements, such as `input` and `textarea`. Try this:

```
// jQuery
const isExpanded = $(this).find('a[aria-expanded]').attr('aria-expanded');
console.log(isExpanded);

// plain JS
const isExpanded = this.querySelector('a[aria-expanded]').getAttribute('aria-expanded');
console.log(isExpanded);
```

Note that both examples assume that `this` is a reference to an [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) object.

Comment: This returns an undefined value. Is there a way to get aria-expanded value of accordion.

Comment: If you're getting `undefined` from this it's likely your selector is incorrect. I'd suggest you start a new question which includes the HTML and JS you're using.

Comment: I'm getting undefined, but I can get the style of the element I want, so I know its not the selector.

Comment: @MH I'd suggest starting a new question including an example of your HTML and JS

Comment: No reason to ask the same question, i'll just get flamed. Its weird this is the marked answer when it doesn't work.

Comment: In which case logic would dictate something is different about your situation. Can you setup a jsFiddle?

Comment: @NormanHuth It appears to work fine in Firefox. I tested with this example: https://jsfiddle.net/8w5htvkb/. Check your own version to verify `this` is referring to a parent element, and the DOM traversal logic is correct. If you still have issues, start a new question but include all your relevant code.

Comment: It may be important to note that this answer does not use the DOM (Document Object Model). It uses JQuery, so you will need to have JQuerry referenced. The answer from @Jon uses the DOM and requires no additional JavaScript libraries.

Comment: @TysonGibby I'd hoped that much was obvious. It follows the example set in the use case outlined in the question.

Answer (score 35):

I wanted to add in a second pure javascript way to get the aria-expanded attribute

```
document.getElementById('test').getAttribute('aria-expanded')
```

The above will get the element by id after that you can get any attribute by name.

Comment: In BS3 this returns null. I cant get style and other attributes, but aria-expanded will only return null. I'm even waiting 1 seconds after page load and its still null.

Comment: Hello M H.  Are you sure aria-expanded is spelled correctly (in my code or on your site). Also are you sure "document.getElementById('test')" is targetting the correct element?

Comment: Figured out why you would get null when using this solution.  You need to wrap it in a setTimeout function to get the correct value of aria-expanded.

Comment: I'm surprised these kind of properties haven't received some shorter accessing like `dataset` yet - would be nice.

Comment: @coder101 As always make sure your certain JS runs AFTER your HTML is created

Comment: @LuckyLukeSkywalker, it is coming :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-expanded#ariamixin_api. This does not have widespread adoption yet.

Comment: @Jon Awesome, good to know, thanks. https://caniuse.com/?search=ariaExpanded https://caniuse.com/?search=ariaChecked . Looks like mostly firefox needs to catch up.

Answer (score 4):

You can use JavaScript to achieve this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].attributes[4].value
```

Step by step explanation:

1. Get the wanted element, by using some selector - here I use the

   ```
   document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
   ```

but you can use any other selector you like.

2. Access the attributes array of the element and find the position of the wanted attribute - in this case that will be 4, because aria-expanded is the 5th attribute of the  tag.
3. From there you just get the value, and that should give you "false" (in this case).

The only problem with this method is that it's a bit hard-coded, so if you add some more attributes to the  tag, the position in the attributes array for the aria-expanded attribute might change.

**UPDATE**

Instead of using the index for accessing the Aria Expanded property, you can use the name:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].attributes['aria-expanded'].value
```

This way you will always get the value for the Area Expanded property, regardless of it's position in the HTML tag.

Comment: I'm not so sure accessing attributes by index rather than key is a good idea. What happens when a new attribute is added before `aria-expanded`, or one is deleted before it?

Comment: That is why I said that the solution is a bit hard-coded.

Answer (score 4):

### Update 12/2023:

`ariaExpanded` property now works in Firefox.  Tested on macOS 14.2, Firefox 120.0.1.

### Update 02/2023:

<s>`ariaExpanded` property still does not work on Firefox.  It will be `undefined`.</s>

---

Another way to get aria values is to reference the properties directly:

For your instance, you could do something like this:

```
let firstAnchorTag = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]; // I don't know your situation but I recommend adding an id to this element, or making this an iterable array.
console.log(firstAnchorTag.ariaExpanded); // Should log 'false' for your example.
```

To get:

```
let el = document.getElementById('foobar');
console.log(el.ariaExpanded); // Should log the current value of aria-expanded.
```

To set:

```
let el = document.getElementById('foobar');
el.ariaExpanded = 'true';
console.log(el.ariaExpanded); // Should log 'true'.
```

Reference: [Element.ariaExpanded MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/ariaExpanded)

Comment: Love it, but it seems Firefox does not have that implemented (yet!?)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/ariaExpanded#browser_compatibility

Comment: Just confirmed today that it doesn't work on Firefox.

Comment: maybe add that to your answer above. I will try to keep an eye on it and comment here once it has been implemented.

Comment: it appears to be working in FF now. You can try it: https://codepen.io/preston206/pen/YzBbXrE

Answer (score 3):

In 2020, I could do:

```
document.querySelector('[aria-expanded]')?.getAttribute('aria-expanded')
```

to grab the first value and maybe something like:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[aria-expanded]'))?
  .map(el => el.getAttribute('aria-expanded'))
```

to make an array of all aria-expanded values.

Answer (score 0):

**attr()** function is used to get value of attribute whereas **val()** is used to retrieve the value attribute from form the related elements, i.e. textbox,input etc. Also **aria-expanded** is an attribute not a class so you are using incorrect selector.
So you should use attr() instead of val().
Use this:

```
console.log($(this).find('a[aria-expanded]').attr('aria-expanded'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element by the class name "accordion-toggle" (if you have it just one time), or better add an ID to the element, and then get the attribute.

```
$('.accordion-toggle').attr('aria-expanded')
```

Or

```
$('#id-name').attr('aria-expanded')
```