# Getting an ID value in to GTM Variable?

Tags: google-chrome, google-tag-manager

[image: Sample code image]

1">

                                                    
                                                    Property 
                                                
                                                
                                                     2">

                                                    
                                                    Personal 
                                                

                                                
                                                     4">

                                                    
                                                    Utilities 
                                                
                                                
                                                     5">

                                                    
                                                    Contact

Want to grab the tab id in to a variable for each click, form will transfer to next tab once all field completes,

Comment: Is there a certain event you want this to happen on? For example, a click on this specific button? Or any button matching a specific selector, like `[role="tab"]`?

Answer (score 1):

To access the `aria-controls` attribute you can use an Auto-Event Variable. To create this:

1. Go to Variables > User-Defined Variables > New
2. Click the Edit icon in the top-right
3. Select Auto-Event Variable
4. For Variable Type, select Element Attribute
5. For Attribute Name, enter `aria-controls`

[image]

Comment: this works fine, but my query now gets complicated, we have a form with 4 tabs, once each form fills up, send to next tab, so i want to get the id of form in each clicks

Comment: yes, for each click, the id is required to identify the click on which tab

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the event. If it's on click, you have `Click ID` as built-in variable for the element ID:

[image]

There's no built-in variable for `aria` attributes, so you'll have to create one. For instance for a click event, you can use the {{Click Element}} which refers to the actual DOM element, and use JavaScript ([Get aria-expanded value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762510/get-aria-expanded-value)) to get aria attribute values:

[image]